# Footprint of current sense resistor for kelvin connection

Tags: pcb, footprint, current-sensor

I need a current sense resistor for my application and I want to add Kelvin connections to it. I found this in the datasheet of a 4 terminal resistor but the footprint doesn't contain "sensing pads". How can I connect this in my PCB? should I edit the footprint and add smaller pads for the Kelvin connection?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you need to provide more info. Are you looking for a resistor component that has these sensing pads, or do you just need the PCB footprint to have extra pads for you to solder something else to?

Comment: It's actually both, I'm looking for a resistor that supports Kelvin connection but I'm having hard time finding the perfect component for my requirements. Although, I found this resistor as a suggestion but the footprint only has 2 pads so I'm also asking if it would solve the problem to add Kelvin connection pads to it.

Answer (score 1):

A kelvin connection can have, but does not require to have, 4 pads on the resistor actually.

It may be done by using any 2-pad resistor by just having two additional traces for voltage measurement that do not cary current (as small as possible :).

[image]

But it may depend on your actual targetted precision and other requirements if you get along with this approach.

Is is as well documented in the [Vishay datasheets](https://www.vishay.com/docs/30133/wsr2-3.pdf), even with dimensions:

[image]

The first image was taken from the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-terminal_sensing) BTW.

Answer (score 0):

you need a resistor designed for this purpose

https://www.koaspeer.com/catimages/Products/CSR/CSR.pdf

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering! While this link may answer the question, it [is better](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/295232) to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes or disappears.

Comment: The problem is that such resistors are available for really small resistance values in the range of 0.1-1mOhm, I need a 20mOhm resistor for my application